# Overwrite all given CSS styles with my CSS selector

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am writing an app for any CMS where I don't know the surrounding CSS or its selectors, but want my app to always look the same.

I'm having the issue, that if a external selector selects one of my elements for example via `button{height: 100px;}` and my selector `button .class{width:100px;}` does not specify the `height` attribute, the external selector puts this attribute onto my buttons and changes its style.

This is just a plain example and you might say, "just specify `height` in your selector, too", i cant put every thinkable attribute into my selectors and overwrite everything that could have somewhere been set.

See this fiddle for an easy example: https://jsfiddle.net/u4rvx6Lk/, where i don't want the first selector to set the border on my blue element, but of course, it does.

I have tried `all: unset;` and `all: initial;` but it just wont work and certainly wont in Internet Explorer.

I also know about scoped CSS but this also doesn't work very reliably.

(Further Info: It is an angular 1.x app that will mainly be injected into WordPress CMS pages, I compile my CSS using sass)

Comment: Maybe you are looking for `important!`

Comment: if i dont set the attribute i cant set !important

Comment: Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/u4rvx6Lk/1/

Comment: It is essentially impossible to stop styles from styling your elements if they have access to them. In a few years you *might* be able to achieve it with the Shadow DOM, but it isn't really possible now. If CSS has access to your elements, it can style them. That's just how it works...

Comment: @lonesomeday but can i overwrite any given attributes with something? similar to all: unset;

Comment: Define a class on the root element of your app. Scope all of your CSS to that root class. Define all properties you may need to override.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution that worked for me is using the CSS property `all` set to a value of `revert`.

```
.css-class {
    all: revert;
}
```

The [mozilla docs for revert](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/revert) explains it nicely:

> The revert CSS keyword rolls back the cascade so that the property takes on the value it would have had if there were no styles in the current style origin.

For  firefox and chrome, use `unset`:

```
.css-class {
    all: unset;
}
```

See [browser hacks](http://browserhacks.com/) for using "media query hacks" for checking the current browser for a cross-browser solution. Also, see this fiddle where the blue box does not inherit the height property:

I hope this solution will work in your project as well.

Comment: it inherits both the height and the border in my chrome and firefox. in your example fiddle

Comment: im sorry, but this changes nothing about the blue boxes style neigther in firefox nor in chrome

Comment: This is happening because `all: unset` unsets all the element's **inherited** properties to their default. `height`, for example, is initially set to `auto` and does not depend on the height of the parent.

Comment: but if i add height:auto; instead of all: unset; it works, so i guess you're wrong about that

Comment: @Jim your fiddle doesnt work because auf the  `//`- Comments, if you update your post i will tag your answer as correct

Answer (score 1):

It is virtually impossible to stop CSS code from modifying your elements, as the web currently exists. What you are essentially talking about is *sandboxing* your elements, preventing them from being modified by other code.

You can do this with an `iframe`, but that's horrid and almost certainly too much faff.

On the other hand, the future is bright! There is a feature coming called the Shadow DOM, which essentially works to allow you to implement your own elements and sandbox them from the rest of your code. It's already how elements like `input` and `video` work behind the scenes: now we get to do what the browsers have been doing for years.

You can create an element: we'll call it `solid-button`.

```
<solid-button></solid-button>
```

We'll then write the code to go inside it. We'll put this in a [`template`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template) so it doesn't appear on the screen till we want it:

```
<template id="solid-button-src">
  <style>
    button {
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      background-color: green;
      border: solid 1px black;
    }

  </style>
  <button></button>
</template>
```

We then use a little bit of Javascript to create the Shadow DOM and add the content in the template into it:

```
customElements.define('solid-button', class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();

    const shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({
      mode: 'open'
    });
    const template = document.querySelector('#solid-button-src');
    const clone = document.importNode(template.content, true);
    shadowRoot.appendChild(clone);
  }
});
```

This works in *some* browsers now, but nowhere near enough to make it production-ready. Your user can apply styles to `solid-button`, but they won't affect the content inside. If you have an up-to-date browser, you can see this in effect below.

Obviously this is not a solution for you now, but it might be the future.

```js
customElements.define('solid-button', class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();

    const shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({
      mode: 'open'
    });
    const template = document.querySelector('template');
    const clone = document.importNode(template.content, true);
    shadowRoot.appendChild(clone);
  }
});
```

```css
button {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  border: solid 1px black;
}

.class1 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}

my-button {
  background: red; /* does nothing visible */
}
```

```html
<button></button>
<button id="id1" class="class1"></button>
<solid-button></solid-button>
<solid-button class="class1"></solid-button>

<template>
  <style>
    button {
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      background-color: green;
      border: solid 1px black;
    }

  </style>
  <button>
    <slot name="content"></slot>
  </button>
</template>
```

Comment: great answer, even if its not right for me as you said. `all: initial` did the job

Answer (score 0):

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u4rvx6Lk/) for an easy example. Unfortunately, the first selector sets the border on my blue element.

The reason the border is being defined on the second box is because it is a `button`, which is where you defined the border. That's how CSS works. If you don't want the border on your second element, you need to either define `border: 0;` on the second element, or in the original selector defining the border, `button`, use something that excludes the second box, like `button:not(#id1)`.

Comment: as I said I have no influence on the first selector and what attributes its specifies. For example it could set a padding or anything else. I wouldnt know it even exists, because i dont know the website my snippet gets injected into, like google maps snippet. It can be applied anywhere. I am looking for a way to prevent external css to affect my elements.

Comment: If the CSS is loaded on the page, you can't keep it from affecting your elements. Best you can do is not load the CSS or remove the stylesheet or style tags via client-side code.

Comment: so you suggest using inline style and removing all classes via classList.remove or something similar?

Comment: Inline if you want, or you can just use `!important`. Using `classList.remove` will remove the classes from the elements themselves, which doesn't sound like your goal, but you can do that if it works for you. In the cases you provided, it wouldn't necessarily work, since in your fiddle, the global rule you want to remove isn't based on a class, it's based on an element name `button`. Modifying `classList` won't fix anything there. If style tags or a stylesheet out of your control are being added to your page, you can remove the style tag or stylesheet entirely, which will remove the styles.

Answer (score 0):

So I somehow made it work. Thanks for the answers.

`all: unset and revert` didnt work for me, `all: initial` did.

Furthermore i will give my internal classes very specific names. Like `class=my-project-class`to prevent external class-selectors from injecting their own attributes.

Also this should not work in IE.

See this Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lvxxnh8r/13/

Comment: Also in this fiddle of mine: https://jsfiddle.net/Lvxxnh8r/14/  `all: unset`works fine. In this  fiddle someone postet: https://jsfiddle.net/Lvxxnh8r/10/ it doenst. I'm very confused.

Comment: I know why: the comments `// Firefox` and so on broke it